# Converting RSA encryption code from .net to PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net

I have some C# .net code I need to convert to PHP, but I'm having a little trouble with it, I'd appreciate any help.

This code basically encrypts a part of an XML, .

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(GetCertificates(certificateSerialNumber).PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(elementsValue), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256")));
```

I have this so far:

```
function encrypt($message) {
    $priv = "---privatekey---";
    openssl_private_encrypt($message, $encrypted, $priv, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

But I can't seem to produce the same encryption as the one by the above code.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a note - the encryption is done with the public key, the decryption runs with the private key. Second don't use Unicode but Utf8 encoding. Merry X-mas

Comment: I know that it is, but the organization I'm dealing with has it the other way around for some reason, and they won't have it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

For RSA, you may use phpseclib:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Remember to use your `private key`.

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privatekey = file_get_contents('private.key');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);

$plaintext = new Math_BigInteger('aaaaaa');
echo $rsa->_exponentiate($plaintext)->toBytes();
?>
```